# Weird behaviour in enumerators in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

According to [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext(v=vs.110).aspx), the enumerator should throw InvalidOperationEx, if the underlying enumerated source was modified. This works when I just get the enumerator directly from IEnumerable.

**THE PROBLEM:** But if I acquire enumerator from "query data structure" , then modify the source and then call MoveNext(), nothing is thrown (see the code).

Consider following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var src = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };           
        var q = src.Where(i => i % 2 == 1);
        IEnumerable<int> nl = src;
        var enmLinq = q.GetEnumerator();
        var enmNonLinq = nl.GetEnumerator();

        src.Add(5); //both enumerators should be invalid, as underlying data source changed     

        try
        {   
            //throws as expected
            enmNonLinq.MoveNext();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("non LINQ enumerator threw...");
        }

        try
        {
            //DOES NOT throw as expected
            enmLinq.MoveNext();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enumerator from LINQ threw...");
        }

        //It seems that if we want enmLinq to throw exception as expected:
        //we must at least once call MoveNext on it (before modification)
        enmLinq.MoveNext();
        src.Add(6);
        enmLinq.MoveNext(); // now it throws as it should
    }
```

It seems you must first call *MoveNext()* method to made it notice the change of underlying source.

**Why I think this is happening:**
I think this is because the "query structure" is giving  you too lazy enumerator, which instead of being initialized on *GetEnumerator()* is initialized during first call to *MoveNext()*.

By initialization I mean connecting all of the enumerators (from *WhereEnumerable, SelectEnumerable* etc structures returned by LINQ methods) on the way down to the real underlying data structure.

**QUESTION:**
Am I right about this or am I missing something?
Do you consider it as weird/wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

The LINQ query will not call `GetEnumerator` on the underlying `List<T>` until you call `MoveNext` on the `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `Where`.

You can see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,c7d6c8b578f62bef) that `MoveNext` is implemented like so:

```
public override bool MoveNext()
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 1:
            enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
            state = 2;
            goto case 2;
        case 2:
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource item = enumerator.Current;
                if (predicate(item))
                {
                    current = item;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Dispose();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the 'initial' state (state 1), it will first call `GetEnumerator` on the `source` before moving to state 2.

Comment: thank you, Do you consider it as bug/inconsistency in MS implementation?

Comment: @videokojot I'd say it was by design.  LINQ is usually as lazy as possible, and it doesn't need the source enumerator until this point (you may never enumerate the query, for example).

Comment: ok, thanks. accepted. Still it seems to me a bit weird but ill live with it.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation only states [execution is deferred until the object is enumerated either by calling its `GetEnumerator` method directly or by using `foreach` in Visual C# or `For Each` in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx).

Since it lacks further detail, the queries performed by LINQ may call `GetEnumerator` on their source either on the first call to their own `GetEnumerator` or as late as possible, such as the first call to `MoveNext`.

I wouldn't assume any particular behavior.

In practice, the actual implementation (see `Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` in the reference source) [defers execution to the first call to `MoveNext`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,c7d6c8b578f62bef).

Answer (score 1):

`enmLinq` is not actualized until first `MoveNext` call. So, any modification done to the `src` prior to calling `MoveNext` will not affect validity of `enmLinq`. Once you call `MoveNext` on `enmLinq` - enumerator is actualized, hence any changes on `src` will lead to exception for the subsequent `MoveNext` call.

Answer (score -1):

You can test this yourself.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var src = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var q = src.Where(i =>
        {
            Output();
            return i % 2 == 1;
        }
        );

        IEnumerable<int> nl = src;
        var enmLinq = q.GetEnumerator();
        var enmNonLinq = nl.GetEnumerator();

        src.Add(5); //both enumerators should be invalid, as underlying data source changed     

        try
        {
            //throws as expected
            enmNonLinq.MoveNext();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("non LINQ enumerator threw...");
        }

        try
        {
            //DOES NOT throw as expected
            // Output() is called now.
            enmLinq.MoveNext();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enumerator from LINQ threw...");
        }

        //It seems that if we want enmLinq to throw exception as expected:
        //we must at least once call MoveNext on it (before modification)
        enmLinq.MoveNext();
        src.Add(6);
        enmLinq.MoveNext(); // now it throws as it should
    }

    public static void Output()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
```

When you run the program, you will see that "Test" is not output to the console until after you call your first MoveNext, which occurs after the source was initially modified.

Comment: thats clear (that the predicate in where is called only when calling MoveNext), but I dont see any connection to my question.